# Web API 2 which is the best way to return empty body for 201 responses

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

In Web API 2 POST method it seems that the best way to respond is using the [CreatedAtRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.createdatroute(v=vs.118).aspx) method. However in certain responses I would like that the body of the response is empty. Thus only replying with 201 and a location header.

I would expect this to work:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Product product)
{
    products.Add(product);
    return CreatedAtRoute<Product>("", new {id = product.Id}, null);
}
```

However inspecting this in Postman, it actually returns a string "null". Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Tried all kinds of combinations here and even using Json.NET as serializer returns "null" (without the quotes). And since it is seen as valid json I might leave it as is. It just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in "Created" method for simplicity but you've said that the response type should be a "Product".

`Created("getPathHere", newProductObject);`

Otherwise, remove the response type of Product, return the new product id instead (and any status that this creation process is in if it isn't instantaneous).

`Created(string.Format("/api/Products/{0}", productId), new { ProductId = productId, Status = "Awaiting Manufacture" });`

Comment: I can't see how that can solve my problem. I do not want anything in the body of the response. All I want is to return code 201 with a location header. No content/body. I would expect this to be possible with the intended Web API 2 response objects and media formatters.

Comment: Because you really ought to be returning something. If you really don't want to return *anything* then remove your response type attribute, use the `Created` helper method and specify null as the object.

Comment: Never thought of that. Removing the return type did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I wrote an action without ResponseType that is using Created(location, (object) null). But I am still getting a null response body

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I wanted to return 201 Created with a location header and an empty response body/content from an action that returns IHttpActionResult and by using Created or CreatedAtRoute I was getting at best null in the response body which wasn't what I wanted. The answer/comment "If you really don't want to return anything then remove your response type attribute, use the Created helper method and specify null as the object." did not help as I did not have a response type attribute specified and also specifying null as the object produced null in the response body .
The solution I found was this:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(mylocationVariable);
return ResponseMessage(response);
```